# MySQL Server Fails to Start on macOS: 'ERROR! Server quit without updating PID file' After Update

Tags: mysql, database, database-connection, mysql-workbench, macos-sonoma

After updating to the latest macOS version, my MySQL Workbench stopped functioning properly. In an attempt to resolve the issue, I completely uninstalled MySQL Community and MySQL Workbench using App Cleaner and Uninstaller, along with various terminal commands sourced from tutorials, ensuring all components of MySQL were fully removed from my computer. My goal was to start afresh by reinstalling everything. However, despite multiple attempts to reinstall and run the MySQL server, I'm facing a consistent and unresolved issue.

Each time I try to start the MySQL server using sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start, it fails, returning the error "ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/iMacs-iMac.local.pid)." I've tried several troubleshooting steps - adjusting file and directory permissions (sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql /usr/local/mysql/data and sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/mysql/data), verifying the absence of a stale PID file (sudo rm /usr/local/mysql/data/iMacs-iMac.local.pid), and updating the PATH environment variable to include MySQL's bin directory. Despite these efforts, the server consistently fails to start, and I've been unable to access the MySQL error log at /usr/local/mysql/data/iMacs-iMac.local.err for more detailed information.

I'm seeking advice on how to troubleshoot this persisting issue on macOS, especially in interpreting the PID file error, or any other strategies that could help resolve the situation. Any insights or guidance from those with experience in MySQL installations on macOS would be greatly appreciated.

Attached are images to illustrate the progression of the issues I'm facing:

Image 1: Displays the initial problem where MySQL Workbench indicates that no MySQL server is running, reflecting the moment the server stopped functioning post macOS update.
Image 2: Shows my terminal log, documenting various attempts to start the MySQL server and adjust environment variables, but repeatedly encountering the error regarding the MySQL PID file.
Image 3: Presents the current state in MySQL Workbench, which remains disconnected from the MySQL server, unable to detect any running instance of MySQL.[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxL3X.jpg)[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXsT5.jpg)[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMdrP.jpg)

- Uninstalled and reinstalled MySQL after macOS update.
- Used App Cleaner and terminal commands for complete removal.
- Expected a fresh install to fix update-related issues.
- Set correct file permissions and removed stale PID files.
- Server still fails to start with "quit without updating PID file" error.
- Expected MySQL to run and connect via MySQL Workbench post-troubleshooting.

Thank you for the help!